# time.strptime() python3 best way to use it?

Tags: validation, date, python-3.x, time, command-line-arguments

basically im trying to check some user input. The user must enter a correct date

YYYYMMDD

and the second argument must be the correct system

MIDRANGE_PROD or MIDRANGE_TEST

Here is my code:

```
def check_user_args(user_args):
    print(user_args[1])
    if(len(user_args[1]) == 8):
        try:
            time.strptime(user_args[1], '%Y%M%d')
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid date! ' + user_args[1])
            sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print('Invalid date!')
        sys.exit(1)
    print(user_args[2])
    if(user_args[2] != 'MIDRANGE_PROD' and user_args[2] != 'MIDRANGE_TEST'):
        print('Invalid system! ' + user_args[2])
        sys.exit(1)
    if(len(user_args) > 3):
        print('to many arguments')
        sys.exit(1)
```

This doesnt feel like the most elegant way to do this? I have though about using a regular expression but this gets complicated quickly when dealing with dates. Also I cant seem to get the time.striptime function work properly it still takes invalid dates

```
D:\oppssup\old_job>python queue_cleaner_main.py 20151929 MIDRANGE_PROD
['queue_cleaner_main.py', '20151929', 'MIDRANGE_PROD']
20151929
MIDRANGE_PROD
```

Update:

So thanks to all reply's. Below is the final solution i implemented for python3

```
# Check command line arguments are correct
def check_user_args(user_args):
    known_systems = {'prod', 'test'}
    try:
        date_string, system_string = sys.argv[1:] #check they only enter 2 arguments
    except ValueError:
        sys.exit('Usage: queue_cleaner <date> <system>')
    try:
        input_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d').date() #Check date format ok
    except ValueError:
        sys.exit('expected date in YYYYMMDD format, got: {}'.format(date_string)) #
    if system_string not in known_systems:
        sys.exit('wrong system, expected: {}, got: {}'.format(' or '
                 .join(known_systems), system_string)) # check correct system entered
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time format is incorrect. You should use `%m` (month) instead of `%M` (minutes). See [strftime() and strptime() behavior](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) in the docs.

If you want to use the data later then just parse it and catch the exceptions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from datetime import datetime

known_systems = {'MIDRANGE_PROD', 'MIDRANGE_TEST'}

try:
    date_string, system_string = sys.argv[1:]
except ValueError:
    sys.exit('Usage: queue_cleaner <date> <system>')

if system_string not in known_systems:
   sys.exit('wrong system, expected: %s, got: %r' % (
       ' or '.join(known_systems), system_string))

try:
    input_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d').date()
except ValueError:
    sys.exit('expected date in YYYYMMDD format, got: %r' % date_string)
```

If you want to support more complex command-line arguments e.g., add optional arguments then use command-line parser such as provided by [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) or [`docopt`](http://docopt.org/) modules.

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies. Chose this answer as it covered all 3 cases but appreciate both answers

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
import re
import datetime

def is_valid_date_str(date_str):
    try:
        datetime.date(*map(int, re.match(r"^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})$", date_str).groups()))
    catch ValueError, AttributeError:
        print('Invalid date! ' + user_args[1])
        sys.exit(1)
```

The line in the try does 3 things:

- First decompose the string into 3 parts with the regular expression,
- then map the captured values to integers,
- and then try to use those values to create a datetime.date.

If the regular expression fails, match returns `None` and `None.groups()` raises an `AttributeError`. If the numbers are not a valid year, month, day tuple, then `datetime.date(y,m,d)` raises `ValueError`.